# Unitary equivalence in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathscr{H}$ and $\mathscr{K}$ be Hilbert spaces and $A\in \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H}), B\in \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{K})$. If $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent then prove that $\|A\|_{\mathscr{H}\rightarrow\mathscr{K}}=\|B\|_{\mathscr{H}\rightarrow\mathscr{K}}$.

I was trying to approach this as it's explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277767/unitary-equivalence-of-compact-operators) however I wasn't able to quite link the two problems as $A$ and $B$ are not compact in this case. How would I proceed to prove the statemeent?

Answer (score 1):

This way simpler than anything like you mentioned. Unitaries are bijections, and they preserve the norm. That's all you need:
\begin{align}
\|B\|=\sup\{\|Bx\|:\ \|x\|=1\}
&=\sup\{\|U^*AUx\|:\ \|x\|=1\}
=\sup\{\|AUx\|:\ \|x\|=1\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\{\|Ay\|:\ \|y\|=1\}=\|A\|. 
\end{align}

Comment: Why is the supremum defined on $\|x\|=1$?

Comment: How do you define the norm?